# Openfire: Create MUC Room with custom fields

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack, multiuserchat

First of all, I'd like to provide some background information: I want to exchange unstructured data between various clients using XMPP. Data sources are supposed to publish their data simply to Mulit-User-Chat rooms ([XEP-0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#registrar)) so that any interested client can register.
XMPP MUC services can have various chat rooms and in order to find the ones my data sources push information to, I'd like to set some custom identification for that room. I figured muc#roominfo_<custom_ident> with some custom value would be great to accomplish that.

For testing purposes I wrote an application that creates a MUC on an XMPP service. Authentication etc. all works fine. I am using Smack to communicate with the XMPP server and to create the room. When I create the room, I am adding a field to the form field I requested before containing my custom information. The MUC is created and accessible. Yet the created custom field is not returned when I perform a disco#info on the room's JID.

I tested this with a local installation of (3.8.2).

I just wonder, if this is an issue of Openfire, that custom form fields ([XEP-0068](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0068.html) used here in XEP-0045) are not stored when the MUC is created or if it is just not allowed according to XEP-0045? I read the specification for MUCs and crucially the respective section but couldn't find any evidence that convinced me, that it is explicitly not possible to create such custom form fields for a MUC.
Maybe I just misunderstand something in the specification? Has anyone tried something similar and it's working? If it is an issue of Openfire, I could try a different XMPP server.

Comment: Have you fond the solution to custom identification for that room. if so, can you share your solution? your help is appreciated

Comment: Sorry for the late response. No, unfortunately I found no solution for this. I ended using the subject and/or description fields to identify the rooms I need.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Even i didn't find any solution for that.